# How to check if a list contains the element passed in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, selenium, protractor

I want to check if the list returned from the application contains the expected element.Please let me know where am going wrong :

```
this.verifyOptionsInDrpDwn = async function(){
      var optionList = await drpDwn.all(by.tagName('option')).getText();
      console.log(optionList);
      var expOptions=['a','b','c','d','e','f'];
      for (let i = 0; i < expOptions.length; i++) {
           var bool=optionList.includes(expOptions[i]);
           console.log(bool);
      }
 }
 
 output :
     [
  '1-a',
  '2-b',
  '3-c',
  '4-d',
  '5-e',
  '6-f'
]

false
```

Comment: your optionList array is [
  '1-a',
  '2-b',
  '3-c',
  '4-d',
  '5-e',
  '6-f'
] hence it isn't the expected output? I'm not sure what you're asking?

Comment: yes, your output example is confusing

Comment: In the actual list , it has '1-a'(for example) but I want to veirfy only if 'a' is there or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) determines whether an array includes a certain value among its entries. But in your case, you want to check if the elements of that array **contain** the value of the expOptions.

If you replace `var bool=optionList.includes(expOptions[i]);`
with `var bool= optionList.some((a) => a.includes(expOptions[i]));`, it should work.

Answer (score 2):

I would do it differently

1. define a method that gets all values

```
this.verifyOptionsInDrpDwn = async function(){
      return drpDwn.all(by.tagName('option')).getText();
 }
```

2. In your spec define expected array and do assertion

```
it('Test spec', async () => {
  let expectedArray = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']
  expect(await pageObject.verifyOptionsInDrpDwn()).toEqual(expectedArray);
});
```

This corresponds to the best practice and your functions are independent and all assertions are part of the test case itself, as it suggests common sense

---

but from JavaScript perspective [.every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) is the way to go

```
this.verifyOptionsInDrpDwn = async function(){
  var optionList = await drpDwn.all(by.tagName('option')).getText();
  var expOptions=['a','b','c','d','e','f'];
  return optionList.length === expOptions.length 
    && optionList.every(elem => expOptions.includes(elem))
 }
```

Not tested, but gives you an idea

Comment: Thank you Sergey.. It worked for me. But its checking for the exact value in the actual list. I want to check if the value contains in the list.Can you pls update on this